# How to get data from backend express server to frontend react app and vice versa

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern, web-development-server

I have a simple backend by express

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

var array = [1,2,3,4,5]

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.send("this is backend of application");
})

app.listen(5000, ()=> console.log("listening on 5000"));
```

and also I have a simple frontend created by create- react-app

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./app"


ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <App />
  </div>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

now my question how can I get that "array" from the backend file to my frontend react file and. vice-versa??

Answer (score 0):

In your component create a method and use built-in fetch API. You can also use `axios`.

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          // set state here
          console.log(result);
        },
        // Note: it's important to handle errors here
        // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
        // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      )
  }
```

Check [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html) for more details.

On node side make these changes:

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

var array = [1,2,3,4,5]

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.send({message: "this is backend of application", data: array});
})

app.listen(5000, ()=> console.log("listening on 5000"));
```

Note: it will be easy if you follow [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-a-react-app-with-a-node-backend-the-complete-guide/) article to create a React app with Node backend.